# Drawing a straight line perpendicular to the x-axis wih Plot

Tags: plotting

I want to plot a straight line perpendicular to the $x$-axis at $x=1$. None of the following attempts work:

```
Plot[EvenQ[x == 1], {x, -1, 2}]
Plot[x == 1, {x, -1, 2}]
Plot[1, {x, -1, 2}]
```

I have only managed to do it with `ContourPlot`:

```
ContourPlot[Evaluate[x == 1], {x, -1, 2}, {y, -1, 2}, Axes -> True]
```

How can I use `Plot` command to draw a straight line perpendicular to the x-axis?

Comment: maybe `Plot[x, {x, -1, 2}, GridLines -> {{1}, None},  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed, Thick]]`?

Comment: Also, `ParametricPlot[{1, x}, {x, -1, 1}]`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Using `InfiniteLine`:** (2nd syntax variation)

If you application requires adding lines only, this should be okay.

```
Plot[Tanh[x], {x, -2, 2}
 , Epilog -> {
   Dashed, Red
   , InfiniteLine[{1, 0}, {0, 1}]
   }
 ]
```

---

**Using `ContourPlot`:**

Much more flexible, as any implicit equation can be plotted with the following method.

```
Show[
 Plot[Tanh[x], {x, -2, 2}]
 , ContourPlot[x == 1
  , {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}
  , ContourStyle -> {Dashed, Red}
  ]
 ]
```

---

*Result:*

[image]

Answer (score 5):

May be Epilog?

```
Plot[x, {x, -1, 2}, Epilog -> Line[{{1, -1}, {1, 3}}]]
```

gives

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can change the style as needed. For example

```
Plot[x, {x, -1, 2}, Epilog -> {Dashed, Red, Line[{{1, -1}, {1, 3}}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
Show[
  Plot[x^2+1/2,{x,-2,2}],
  ListPlot[{{1,0},{1,4}},Joined->True]
]
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments:

```
Plot[x, {x, -1, 2}, GridLines -> {{1}, {}}, GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Red, Dashed]]
```